# Creating PHP & MysQL system and keep it up-to-date with online copy

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization, offlineapps

i'm on my way to create a PHP/MysQl web application to run on online server, and i need to install it on multiple laptop so they can use the application without any internet connection, in this case i need to find the best solution to keep all the databases updated, so i have 2 questions i really need your help on it,

1- what is the best solution to link offline and online MysQl databases together?
2- can i install the application with it Database without using desktop server (Wamp, Xampp...)? i mean i have about 30 laptops so i need a solution to install it with one click, i already tried PHP Desktop but i have Macs.

thank you.

Comment: Can you not simply install macOS Server on one of your Macs and use it a local server? Then, all you have to do is use it through your local network (it will serve all your Macs) and voilà. You can also keep that local server connected to the internet to manage all the updates while keeping all other Macs offline. I really don't understand what you want to do, honestly.

Comment: Hello Zeke, let's say one of the staff is not in the office but he need to work on the system, so this local server will not help me, what i need to do is a system that can run offline on multiple laptops and synced with online database when that laptop connected to the internet.

Comment: Well, in that case I don't see why you want to build a **web** application, isn't it easier to build a desktop app that syncs when connected to the internet? Anyway, fortunately for you, Macs come with a web server built-in that you can use but it's disabled by default. [Here's one example on how to enable it](https://websitebeaver.com/set-up-localhost-on-macos-high-sierra-apache-mysql-and-php-7-with-sslhttps), but it's kinda long so you'll most likely enable only the basics and leave it at that. You still have to do it on every Mac though, or else you can't manage requests.

Comment: As for updating, you'll most likely have to run a script when you first open the system and, if connected to the internet, pull the updates. How to do that is up to the script you create for it. Another way would be to create a cron service that runs that script every once in a while (you choose how often) and have it check if the computer is connected to the internet before running the whole thing. Just don't forget to push the changes made.

Comment: Thanks Zeke, is it possible to link desktop app with Mysql / PHP online web app?

Comment: It is, but the script must take a lot of things into consideration. What if a user pulls information, works on it, and before uploading the changes someone else uploads changes they made? How can you make sure these two sets of information don't collide? You see, it's not as easy as "I'll just push the information and deal with it", you have to remember that maybe all computers are working at the same time. As long as you can solve that part, you'll be fine. But you can definitely do it.

Comment: That's very helpful, really thank you Zeke, and let's see if there's any other recommendations from the community before i begin with this system.

Comment: Here's my thought: you have Macs, therefore the app must run on macOS if built as a desktop app (best choice, in my opinion). This desktop app will have its own database to work offline. A server will have the only fully updated production-ready database. Whenever the Mac is connected to the internet, look for possible updates on the server (background) and, if found, let the user know and choose whether to pull them or not. When offline changes are done, let the user upload them to the online server, not forgetting to check for updates one last time before doing so. That's the basics.